# ASIHTTPRequest package in new application

Tags: iphone, web-services, ios5, ios5.1

I am using ASIHTTRequest in one of my new applications for all web service call. I know support for it is stopped. I wanted to know app submission will go smooth if I am still using ASIHTTPRequest? (I want to know if someone recently used ASIHTTP with new app submission and it went through Apple review process..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with using ASIHTTPRequest. I have had at least 20 apps approved this year using it and one approved as recently as Friday night September 21, 2012.